# Way to iterate through a string xe-1/2/3 in Python

Tags: python

I have been trying this but have not got anywhere.

I extract multiple values of type xe-1/2/3 and so on. I have to write a python script in such a way that,

- for xe-1/1/3,
  if it is 1, and the next value is 1, the value gets saved for FPC1: PIC1
- for xe-1/2/3
  if it is 1, and the next value is 2, the value gets saved for FPC1: PIC2
- for xe-2/1/3
  if it is 2, and the next value is 1, the value gets saved for FPC2: PIC1

Pseudo code would be:

```
value = "xe-1/2/3"
value.split("/")
if value[0].endswith("1"):
    if [value[1].startswith("0"):
    print "FPC1: PIC1"
```

But, I intend to not hard code the values, since the value is a list of many values which is extracted from an xml file. All the data that is extracted needs to be further printed in a text file.

Open to any suggestions on how all this data needs to be saved, for now I am using simple ways just printing it directly

and so on ...

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

Comment: What do you mean by "values of type xe-1/2/3 and so on"? We're missing a lot of information regarding how your data is stored, what data types are involved, the exact format of what you want to extract, etc.

Comment: values of type xe-1/2/3 means there are many  strings of similar type in a list like ['xe-1/2/3','xe - 1/2/4', ...... 'xe-n/n/n']

Comment: Pseudo code would be:

value = xe-1/2/3
value.split("/")
if value[0].endswith("1"):
    if [value[1].startswith("0"):
    print "FPC1: PIC1"
But, I intend to not hard code the values, since the value is a list of many values which is extracted from an xml file. All the data that is extracted needs to be further printed in a text file.

Open to any suggestions on how all this data needs to be saved, for now I am using simple ways just printing it directly

Comment: @James , I have been struggling for days now, need help!

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions. This includes how much of a struggle it is, or how many days you've been struggling - that's another way of making exhausting emotional appeals to volunteers here in their free time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just split the string into segments, and analyse the parts you want.

```
def identify(value):
    a,b,c = value.split('/')
    return 'FPC{0}: PIC{1}'.format(a.split('-')[1], b)
```

So identify('xe-1/1/3') results in a value of 'FPC1: PIC1'

Comment: I do not want to hard code the values, like the 0, 1 and stuff, it needs to be dynamically extracted and used.

Comment: LOL... dude, they aren't hardcoded... the 0 and 1 are position numbers in the format function.  0 takes the first value, 1 takes the second value...

The function does exactly what you wanted, and is dynamic.  Not sure why you dinged me for giving a quick, and valid answer...

Comment: Lol, my bad ! I should have seen properly and implemented before commenting ! Thanks and Apologies, this works !